# Return a response from axios GET

Tags: axios, return, response, innerhtml

function sendrcp() {
const url = "./api/recptId";

```
        axios
          const data.get(`${url}/${sopN.value}`)
          .then(function (res) {
            return res.data;
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });

        return res.data;
      }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wanted to display the response from the get method, but the function was nested so the second function wasn't retrieving my response as expected.